# Jackson cannot deserialize JSON with HAL elements

Tags: java, json, spring, hal

I am using Spring Data Rest to create simple REST API, returning JSON with HAL (by default). It looks like this:

```
{
"_embedded" : {
"students" : [ {
  "studentNumber" : 1,
  "studentName" : "test",
  "studentSurname" : "test",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/students/2"
    },
    "student" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/students/2"
    }
  } ]
},
"_links" : {
"self" : {
  "href" : "http://localhost:8080/students"
},
"profile" : {
  "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile/students"
},
"search" : {
  "href" : "http://localhost:8080/students/search"
    }
  }
}
```

That is my Student entity class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Entity(name = "students")
public class Student {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "student_number")
private Long studentNumber;

@Column(name = "student_name")
private String studentName;

@Column(name = "student_surname")
private String studentSurname;

//getters, setters
}
```

When I want to deserialize this using Jackson, it gives me an error: Can not deserialize instance of pl.rasztabiga.springdatarest.entity.Student[] out of START_OBJECT token

But when I want to deserialize it manually, skipping "_embedded" and "students" parts, it is working properly (like in normal JSON, without HAL). Yes, I am registering Jackson2HalModule in ObjectMapper, but still gives me same error.

Comment: It looks like your JSON is wrong. Before ending students array by ']' you are missing  '}' to end student object.

Comment: Maybe I copied it wrong, but it's good JSON, automatically generated by Spring Data Rest

Comment: Could you show us how exactly you do the deserialization?

Comment: Would've liked to find out more about this one ...